# How to control the order of the fragments being loaded in my app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to embed the fragments API to an application but I can't control the order of fragments being loaded and thus getting some exceptions.
I configure my layout this way:

```
 <fragment class="org.me.myListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frag_title"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
 <fragment class="org.me.DetailsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/details"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"

        />

</FrameLayout>
```

But the DetailsFragment is being loaded before the list fragment and this causes trubles.
I don't want to break the old code, controlling the order here would be the quickest way to fix it.
Is there a way I can make the second fragment to be initialized only after the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot control the order if you use `<fragment>` elements. If you switch to dynamic fragments (e.g., `FragmentTransaction`), you control when fragments are created, because you create them.

IMHO, one fragment should not depend upon another fragment in the manner that you describe.